# Check if model/session exist and is not null in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I've built an exit intent popup that will be shown when a user wants to exit the site. This popup will then save an entry to the database (as long as the dropdown is selected and client has a valid unique key). This all works great.

The problem I'm facing is that the popup should not show if the user does not have a valid unique key assigned to them  (created when first page is submitted). This key is found in a Session (this session is a class object)...

This is how it is created:

Class Object:

```
    public class PolicyBase
    {
        //This will hold the whole object in terms of the policy

        public string SessionKey { get; set; }
        public int polKey { get; set; }
        //Other items
    }
```

Setting the Sessions:

```
    public class SessionHelper
    {
    #region Session INIT

    public static PolicyBase PolicyBase
    {
        get { return GetSession<PolicyBase>("PolicyBase"); }
        set { SetSession("PolicyBase", value); }
    }
    }
```

This is my javascript running in the General.js page which is used across the website. Showing the popup is working is working fine:

```
    addEvent(document, "mouseout", function (e) {
    e = e ? e : window.event;
    var from = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;
        if (!from || from.nodeName == "HTML") {
            //if (event.clientY <= 0 || event.clientX <= 0 || (event.clientX >= window.innerWidth || event.clientY >= window.innerHeight)) {
            if (event.clientY <= 0 || (event.clientY >= window.innerHeight)) {
                $("#dialog-exit-intent").modal("show");
            }
        }
});
```

This is what I tried to check for the session in javascript (this is not working):

```
    addEvent(document, "mouseout", function (e) {
    e = e ? e : window.event;
    var from = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;

   // var session = '<%= Session["PolicyBase"] %>';
    var session = localStorage.getItem("PolicyBase")
    alert(session);

    var varQuoteKey = localStorage.getItem("PolicyBase"); // '<%= Session["PolicyBase"] %>';
    if (session.val() != null && session.val() != '') {

        if (!from || from.nodeName == "HTML") {
            //if (event.clientY <= 0 || event.clientX <= 0 || (event.clientX >= window.innerWidth || event.clientY >= window.innerHeight)) {
            if (event.clientY <= 0 || (event.clientY >= window.innerHeight)) {
                $("#dialog-exit-intent").modal("show");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Basically what I want to do is check if the session exist and that it is not null (e.g. c# code that works)

```
    public ActionResult SavePolicyLeaveReason(int exitIntentLeaveReasonKey)
    {
        var polBase = SessionHelper.PolicyBase;
        //some code 

        if (polBase != null)
        {
            //some code
            polStatus = "T";
        }
        else
        {
            polStatus = "F";
        } 
        return Json(polStatus);
    }
```

Is there any way for me to accomplish this? Or is there a better solution to this? 
I've read about waiting for the page to finish loading, but even after this is done, the above will still be an issue)

Comment: Session variables are server-side only. You would have to make an ajax call to the server at the point where you display the popup

Comment: If you do not want to make an additional ajax call, you can add the object to the page model and bind it from there

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going to try the ajax call. Adding the object to the page model is not preferred as this will then need to be done on all pages (need to be generic and used across all current and future pages)....